# How to avoid using if elif loop for plotting graph for dataframe below as data frame consists of may rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, if-statement, bar-chart

```
def f(genre):
    

    if genre=="Action":
        plt.bar(df2.Name[:5], df2.Global_Sales[:5])
        
    elif genre=="Adventure":
        plt.bar(df2.Name[5:10], df2.Global_Sales[5:10])
```

[image]
How do you shorten the code as dataframe cosnsist of many rows and I want to avoid using if ,elif for thee data frame

Comment: You can use boolean masking as: `df2.loc[df2['Genre'] == 'Action', 'Name']`.  This will return a Series of `Name` values where `Genre` meets (a) criteria.

Comment: `df[df['Genre'] == 'Action'].plot.bar(x='Name', y='Global_Sales')` ?

Comment: Instead of a PNG, include code that initializes a datatframe. That gives a base for posting working solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Documented inline

```
def f(df2, genre):
    # get subset of dataframe matching the given genre
    df = df2[df2['Genre'] == genre]
    # If such a non empty subset exits, plot it
    if len(df) > 0:
       plt.bar(df.Name, df.Global_Sales)
```

Comment: Suggestion: Generally better to use `if not df.empty`.